# Loop through each folder and concatenate files (output a combined file in each folder)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I wish to loop through a number of folders and concatenate all the .html files, and output a combined.html for EACH folder, via a batch file.

Even better, I wish to output a combined[foldername].html.  For example, for Folder1, the output concatenated file in that folder will be combinedFolder1.html.

I have been going into each folder to concatenate the files by using the copy command in Command Prompt:

```
copy *.html combined.html
```

How can I loop through a number of folders and run the copy command for concatenation and output a combined.html (or combined[foldername].html) for each folder using a batch file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch this in the main folder.  It should do what you require.

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
   pushd "%%a"
   echo "%%a"
      copy *.html tmp.tmp >nul
      move /y tmp.tmp "combined%%~nxa.html" >nul
   popd
)
pause
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it does, and how do you run above? What is `/d` `/r` `/y` are used for?

Comment: @vadimbog `/d` gathers directory names, and `/r` does it recursively.  `/y` ensures the file is overwritten if it already exists.  The function is described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Below one-line command should do what you need:

`find . -type d ! -path '.' | xargs -i_folder sh -c "cd _folder; cat *html > combined\$(echo _folder | sed 's#.*/##').html"`

I shall also mention that above assumes your directories does not contain spaces in their names.

In case it does then some changes here which shall solve the problem:

`find . -type d ! -path '.' -print0 | xargs --null -i_folder sh -c "cd \"_folder\"; cat *html > \"combined\$(echo _folder | sed 's#.*/##').html\""`

Comment: It seems that the question has a `Windows` tag and your solution won't work in generic Windows.

Comment: :) My bad, didn't notice that. This explains also your solution (not familiar with scripting in windows).